# x509: certificate signed by unknown authority PANIC: Failed to register this runner

Tags: gitlab, runner

```
ERROR: Registering runner... failed
runner=J4DBd8we
status=couldn't execute POST against https://tarun-labs.local/api/v4/runners:
  Post https://tarun-labs.local/api/v4/runners: x509:
    certificate signed by unknown authority PANIC:
      Failed to register this runner
```

Hi I am facing same problem and tried searching many forums for answers and didn't got any solution yet. **config.toml** file location is not clear as the one I saw is not the right one I think It is in **/gitlab-runner** folder and shows only 3 parameters: **[Concurrent][check Interval]** and **[Session Server]**. So now way I can change any Value. As I am registering the runner ..the [runners] tab is not expected to be there.

I am trying this on home lab therefore do we need a "single" self signed certificate or need to have CA Certificate as well. Not clear [Full Chain ? or only CA+Server Cert]. I am using home lab so cannot arrange certificate from Pubic CA.

Also is there a way I can skip this error by bypassing SSL? I have seen tls verify or ssl verify option to be set to `no`.. Where to put that is not clear or mentioned in any forum whatsoever.

This should be common problem for many as fresh installation does not give you any runner to begin with so everyone should be doing these steps. Please help anyone?

Comment: GitLab Community Edition 13.2.1 is being used for Now

Comment: have you found the solution to it? I am having the same problem too.

Answer (score 1):

From [gitlab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/tls-self-signed.html).

```
GitLab Runner reads the PEM certificate (DER format is not supported) from a predefined file:

1 - /etc/gitlab-runner/certs/hostname.crt on *nix systems when GitLab Runner is executed as root.

2 - ~/.gitlab-runner/certs/hostname.crt on *nix systems when GitLab Runner is executed as non-root.

3 - ./certs/hostname.crt on other systems. If running Runner as a Windows service, this will not work. Use the last option instead.

If your server address is: https://my.gitlab.server.com:8443/, create the certificate file at: /etc/gitlab-runner/certs/my.gitlab.server.com.crt. To verify that the file looks correct, you can use a tool like openssl.
```